# Rebuilding/Parsing plain JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parsing

Let's say I have an *`object containing objects that have 30 key-value pairs`* each:

```
const data = {
        "foo": {
            "3/16/21": 'buzz',
            "3/17/21": 'fizz',
            ...
            "4/13/21": 'lorem',
            "4/14/21": 'ipsum'
        },
        "bar": {
            "3/16/21": 'sit',
            "3/17/21": 'amet',
            ...
            "4/13/21": 'dummy',
            "4/14/21": 'text'
        },
    };
```

My goal is to rebuild this object into something like this:

```
myData = [
        {date: "3/16/21", foo: 'buzz', bar : 'sit'}
        {date: "3/17/21", foo: 'fizz', bar : 'amet'} ,
            ...
        {date: "4/13/21", foo: 'lorem', bar : 'dummy'}
        {date: "4/14/21", foo: 'ipsum', bar : 'text'}
         ];
```

The function below works like charm but I feel like there is a 10x better way to do it. I would love to see your suggestions on how I could improve it.

```
const processAPIdata = (data) => {
        if (data) {
            var myData = [];

            for (var key in data) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                var obj = data[key];
                for (var prop in obj) {

                    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                    if (myData.length < 30) {
                        myData.push({ date: prop });
                    }
                    let pos = myData.map(function (e) { return e.date; }).indexOf(prop);
                    myData[pos][key] = obj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
        return myData;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd group into an object indexed by date. When iterating, create the object for that date if it doesn't exist yet, with `{ date }` (where `date` is the inner property being iterated over), and assign a new property from the outer key (for the new key) and the inner value (for the new value):

```js
const data = {
    "foo": {
        "3/16/21": 'buzz',
        "3/17/21": 'fizz',
        "4/13/21": 'lorem',
        "4/14/21": 'ipsum'
    },
    "bar": {
        "3/16/21": 'sit',
        "3/17/21": 'amet',
        "4/13/21": 'dummy',
        "4/14/21": 'text'
    },
};

const newDataByDate = {};
for (const [key, obj] of Object.entries(data)) {
  for (const [date, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    newDataByDate[date] ??= { date };
    newDataByDate[date][key] = val;
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(newDataByDate));
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what the ??= operator is doing?

Comment: It assigns the expression on the right if it doesn't exist yet. More verbosely: `if (!newDataByDate[date]) { newDataByDate[date] = { date }; }`

Comment: Your solution seems to be working as expected. But what if I would want to iterate thought this object later. Seems like doing so with array of objects could be much easier.

Comment: ? My code (and your expected output) both produces an array of objects. I guess if you wanted to look up objects by their date you could keep using the `newDataByDate` object if you wanted, but it sounds like you want an array of objects, not an object of objects.

Comment: I'm getting an object of objects with your code, I'll be using the array indexes later

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" in my answer to see the result: you will see that it is an array of objects, just like you wanted.

Comment: could it be that I'm getting object of objects because of `if (!newDataByDate[date]) { newDataByDate[date] = { date }; };` ?

Comment: No. If you use the code in my answer, you will see an array of objects get logged. Like I said, press "Run code snippet", or just copy my code and run it, and you should see it too. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jskUh.png

Comment: Yes, I'm getting array when running code snippet. I probably messed up somewhere in VScode

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) & [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like below

```js
const data = {"foo":{"3/16/21":'buzz',"3/17/21":'fizz',"4/13/21":'lorem',"4/14/21":'ipsum'},"bar":{"3/16/21":'sit',"3/17/21":'amet',"4/13/21":'dummy',"4/14/21":'text'}};

const formatData = (data) => {
//Convert the object to array of arrays with value at first index being the keys and value at second index being values
  const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  //Since we have object as value, we need to again convert to array of arrays in order to get the date and the corresponding value
    Object.entries(val).forEach(([date, innerVal]) => {
    //update the accumulator with new key-value
      acc[date] = {
        ...(acc[date] || {date}),
        [key]: innerVal
      }
    })
    return acc;
  }, {});

//Return the values of the accumulator
  return Object.values(result);
}

console.log(formatData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can complete by doing this simple way.

```js
const data = {"foo":{"3/16/21":'buzz',"3/17/21":'fizz',"4/13/21":'lorem',"4/14/21":'ipsum'},"bar":{"3/16/21":'sit',"3/17/21":'amet',"4/13/21":'dummy',"4/14/21":'text'},};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  for(const [date, v] of Object.entries(values)){
    acc[date] = acc[date] || {date}
    acc[date][[key]] = v;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```